# Reset form with Formik using Fromik 2.01RC

Tags: reactjs, formik

Using Formik 2.01RC, tring to use resetForm from onClick event witout success.

If i put button with reset property on resetForm onClick event its working

```
 <div className="sendAgain" onClick={this.sendCodeAgain.bind(this, resetForm)}>
    <IntlMessages id="login.resendCode" />
</div>
```

**Update**: with sendCodeAgain :

```
 sendCodeAgain(resetForm) {
    const { getCode, auth } = this.props
    resetForm();
    getCode(auth.phone);
  }
```

Comment: Can you include `sendCodeAgain` snippest of code?

Comment: sendCodeAgain(resetForm) {
    const { getCode, auth } = this.props
    resetForm();
    getCode(auth.phone);
  }

Comment: try this: `resetForm({})` instead of `resetForm()`, just give it an empty object as a parameter.

Comment: didint works!
im using  "formik": "^2.0.1-rc.12",

Comment: I have been all around the code base for that version, it didn't give any clues on how to do `resetForm` in another way than passing an empty object, can you make a Reproducible example for your code with [codesandbox](http://codesandbox.io)?